# SharePoint 2013 - Possible to have a different theme for each Wiki Page?

Tags: 2013, wiki, theme, pages

In SharePoint 2013, I understand that it is possible to have different themes in place across the team websites, or subsites. I am interested in the Wiki pages found under a single team website-- Is it possible to have a different theme (like color scheme, and background picture) for each Wiki Page?

Currently, I can only set a single theme for a single team website, and that theme touches across all pages found in that team website.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a theme is only applied to the site for which it is selected. It is not inherited by any subsites unless you are working with a publishing site., Or, if the publishing feature was enabled for a site, you can choose to either inherit the theme from the parent site or specify a theme that will be used by the site.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424397.aspx

You can set the theme for Site but for the individual page, I never heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set theme by page. You could create different CSS files or master pages and apply them to individual pages.