# Different theme per page in a sub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

I would like to know if there is a way to set different theme for different page in same subsite in SharePoint Office 365.

I checked the below question which is for SP 2013
[SharePoint 2013 - Possible to have a different theme for each Wiki Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172388/sharepoint-2013-possible-to-have-a-different-theme-for-each-wiki-page)

Also if it is not possible out of the box, is there any customized solution using which I can achieve this? Any pointer would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, set different themes for different pages is not available.

When you change the theme in the site collection, the theme of subsite will change accordingly.

You could create different CSS files or master pages then apply them to individual pages.

Comment: Thank you Emily!

Comment: You're welcome.